# Value Successfully of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android

```
final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Verifying", "Please wait...", false, false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
     try {
      loading.dismiss();
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
      String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
         if (code.equals("login_failed")) {
             builder.setTitle("Login Error");
             displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
             } else {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Success.class);
               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
               bundle.putString("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));
               intent.putExtras(bundle);
               startActivity(intent);

           }
        }
```

Comment: share your response.

Comment: @HemantParmar :) You meant probably question? I really agree that a nice and clear question here would make everyone's lives much easier.

Comment: you are parsing response in volley by use of JssonArrray, i want this JSON response so i can check where you get wrong.

Comment: @Mohit, you are getting the response as String which is "Success" of type string. Could you confirm your Request method, bcoz i see that you are posting the Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `Response.Listner<String>` to `JSONArray` like below code

```
 new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                    try {
                                        loading.dismiss();
                                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                         String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                                        if(code.equals("login_failed"))
                                        {

                                            builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                                            displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                        }
                                        else {

                                            Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,Success.class);
                                            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                                            bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                            bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
                                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                            startActivity(intent);

                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to parse **String data into JSONArray**.

here

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
```

change this to

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: @MohitTripathi make sure you are using `JSONObject ` , if possible please update your question with your new code .

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value in the variable `response` holds some other value other than array.

try using json object and print/debug the value.

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
        loading.dismiss();
         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
         }
        }
    }
```